# Delete nodejs devDependencies

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Is there a way to delete devDependencies in nodejs without deleting everything. I have no npm on the destination server so I do the following:

```
$ npm install
$ grunt build
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm install --production
```

Does anyone know if there exists an npm module that can purge installed modules. TIA!

Comment: what's wrong with keeping them? when i deploy to heroku, `npm install` doesn't install the `devDependencies`, so i included my `devDependencies` in `dependencies`, is that bad?

Comment: Thanks. For heroku it may work but heroku has npm and it probably deletes them to save the space (because it knows you won't be needing them during production). In my case the destination has no npm and I don't want to send files that are not needed.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use [npm prune --production](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune)

Comment: `I have no npm on the destination server` - OP.